# Iteritems return formatted strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm pretty noobish at Python, so I'm hoping this is a simple question. I'm trying to loop through a dictionary and return formatted strings for them. I can print out the formatted strings no problem, but I'm trying to make it into a function so that I can run tests.

ex.

```
somedict = {'dog':'bone', 'cat':'nip'}

def Something(somedict):
    for key, value in somedict.iteritems():
        my_str = '%s and %s.' % (key, value)
        return my_str
```

This returns `'dog and bone'` but I'd like it to say `'dog and bone.cat and nip'`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Dicts don't have any order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return the *first* item only. Join the results:

```
def Something(somedict):
    return '.'.join(['%s and %s' % (key, value) for key, value in somedict.iteritems()])
```

This joins all key-value pairs with newlines, but you can pick any join string you like, including the empty string.

Demo:

```
>>> Something(somedict)
'dog and bone.cat and nip.'
```

Just take into account that dictionaries have no fixed ordering, depending on the insertion and deletion history of your dictionary the output order can differ.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yup. And my answer states: 'you can pick any join string you like'.